# How can I get my code to work in a greater scope?

Tags: excel, vba

Code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
 
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("H2").Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), _
        Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
 
End Sub
```

Is it possible to increase the scope of the code so that no matter where a date is entered in column A (below the A2 starting parameter) the date and row will be sorted into the correct location? Currently this code only allows the space directly after the final entry to sort.
Example:

| Date | Other Info |
| --- | --- |
| 5/12/2022 | ""Data |
| 5/18/2022 | ''Data |
| **5/17/2022** | ''Data |

This produces a chart where the 5/17 will move between the 5/12 and 5/18 as it should

Example2:

| Date | Other Info |
| --- | --- |
| 5/12/2022 | ""Data |
| 5/18/2022 | ''Data |
| -------- | -------------- |
| **5/17/2022** | ''Data |

This however results in nothing occurring which is what I want to increase the scope for. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could detect the last used row (examining column A) each time the event runs, with something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ws As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A2:H" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), _
        Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
 
End Sub
```

However, an easier way would be to just use the `Target.Row`, as this should suffice in your circumstances:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A2:H" & Target.Row).Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), _
        Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
 
End Sub
```

Obviously, if your table goes beyond column H, then you'll need to change that.